# How disabling the code analysis at design time for a database project - Visual Studio 2022 plus SSDT extension

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm developing a database project to implement a db versus a Synapse dedicated SQL pool, by using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 vers. 17.8.3 plus SSDT extension.
After some script created, I've noticed that Visual Studio runs more slowly because a database schema analysis is in progress, reading the message shown in the status bar: the database projects are ready after the completion of some thousands of operations.
Now, is it possible to disable the code analysis at design time for a database project in order to work more quickly, please? Thanks
I've read this article but it seems not much useful --> [Database Project Settings - SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/database-project-settings?view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk_code_analysis)